# Symfony 3 unit test form with constructor

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to unit test a form which has 2 dependencies (ObjectManager and EventDispatcher)

I had tried to follow [official doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/unit_testing.html#testings-types-from-the-service-container) but without success.

My testing file:

```
<?php

namespace Lch\MediaBundle\Tests\Form;

use Lch\MediaBundle\Form\AddImageType;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\PreloadedExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;

class AddImageTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    private $entityManager;
    private $eventDispatcher;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->entityManager = $this->createMock(ObjectManager::class);
        $this->eventDispatcher = $this->createMock(EventDispatcher::class);

        parent::setUp();
    }

    protected function getExtensions()
    {
        $type = new AddImageType($this->entityManager, $this->eventDispatcher);

        return array(
            new PreloadedExtension(array($type), array()),
        );
    }

    public function testSubmitValidData()
    {
        $form = $this->factory->create(AddImageType::class);
    }
}
```

I got this error when I execute my test suite:

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   LCH\MediaBundle\Form\AddImageType::__construct() must implement
>   interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, none given,
>   called in
>   /home/matthieu/www/lch/media/src/Lch/MediaBundle/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php
>   on line 85

It seems that the job I do in the getExtensions method is not working, but cannot figure it out.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjectManager` is an interface, meaning you can't instantiate or pass it directly to other constructors.

If you are using Doctrine, replace it with `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` which implements `ObjectManager` interface and can be instantiated, otherwise replace it with your own implementation.

```
<?php

namespace Lch\MediaBundle\Tests\Form;

use Lch\MediaBundle\Form\AddImageType;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\PreloadedExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;

class AddImageTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    private $entityManager;
    private $eventDispatcher;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->entityManager = $this->createMock(EntityManager::class);
        $this->eventDispatcher = $this->createMock(EventDispatcher::class);

        parent::setUp();
    }

    protected function getExtensions()
    {
        $type = new AddImageType($this->entityManager, $this->eventDispatcher);

        return array(
            new PreloadedExtension(array($type), array()),
        );
    }

    public function testSubmitValidData()
    {
        $form = $this->factory->create(AddImageType::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Might want to read up a bit on mocking.  Nothing wrong with mocking an interface plus take a look at the error message.